# Selecting a random list element of length n in Python

Tags: python, random

I know you can use random.choice to choose a random element from a list, but I am trying to choose random elements of length 3. For example,

```
list1=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

I want the output to look something like:

```
[c,d,e]
```

Essentially I want to generate random sub-lists from the list.

Comment: Do you want 3 consecutive elements or 3 random elements?

Comment: 3 consecutive elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
idx = random.randint(0, len(list1)-3)
list1[idx:idx+3]
```

Comment: Wow should have thought of this. A very simple solution!

Answer (score 20):

Use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to pick a list of 3 elements:

```
random.sample(list1, 3)
```

Demo code:

```
>>> import random
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c' ,'d' ,'e' ,'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> random.sample(list1, 3)
['e', 'b', 'a']
```

If you needed a sublist, then you are stuck with picking a random start index between 0 and the length minus 3:

```
def random_sublist(lst, length):
    start = random.randint(len(lst) - length)
    return lst[start:start + length]
```

Which works like this:

```
>>> def random_sublist(lst, length):
...     start = random.randint(len(lst) - length)
...     return lst[start:start + length]
... 
>>> random_sublist(list1, 3)
['d', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the result to wrap around to the start of the list you can do:

```
idx = randint(0, len(list1))
(list1[idx:] + list1[:idx])[:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a random subset of the original list, you can use

```
import random
random.sample(your_list, sample_size)
```

However, if you want your sublists to be contiguous (like the example you've given), you might be better off picking two random indices and slicing the list accordingly:

```
a = random.randint(0, len(your_list) - sample_length)
sublist = your_list[a:b+sample_length]
```

Comment: This gives lists of random lengths.

Comment: @MartijnPieters- Oops! Misread the question. Corrected, thanks!